# Jinja2 globals request documentation

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking for all of the associated attributes for the Jinja2 request globals variable and I can't seem to find it listed in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-context).

I'm trying to print out the url without any pages within my meta tag by doing such:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ request.url_rule }}" />
```

But this prints out the URL with any associated pages (ie. '/contact', etc). I know that I could just define this as a globals variable myself easily but I wanted to see the proper way of doing such and avoid defining extra variables.

Is there a way to print out the base URL from the request variable?

Answer (score 0):

[request.url_root](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.url_root)  - from Flask.request object

> The full URL root (with hostname), this is the application root as IRI. See also: trusted_hosts.